# Php, пользование сессией

Tags: php, сессия

Недавно начала учить php и задалась вопросом: как с помощью самой сессии (пока что без SQL) сделать так, что при одноразовом правильном вводе пароля он больше не спрашивался? Т.е. при переходе на ссылку сайта не открывалась страница входа, а сразу контент. Как, например, в ВК или другим соц. сетях.

Comment: Покажите что вы уже попробовали.

Comment: @E_p, я ещё, толком, ничего и не пробовала. Умею, вот,  выводить к-во сессий: http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_13/index.php . Я просто даже не представляю как определить план действий, как я привыкла делать. Не особо понимаю эту часть php.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/ru/session.examples.php

Comment: @E_p, спасибо за помощь :з

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если очень упростить:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['password']) && password_verify($_POST['password'], $hash)) {
    // пароль проверен - отметим это в сессии
    $_SESSION['password_ok'] = true;
}

if (empty($_SESSION['password_ok'])) {
    // новый пользователь - показываем форму запроса пароля
} else {
    // пароль был проверен успешно - показываем контент
}
```

Хеш пароля вы храните в БД или в файле, [получаете с помощью функции password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Answer (score 0):

После успешной авторизации записывай в сессию успех авторизации.

Когда пользователь обращается к твоей странице ты смотришь в сессии  успех авторизации. Если есть положительный - то ты грузишь ему страницу с контентом, иначе - ты грузишь ему страницу с авторизацией.

Это если на котах.